# overload inserter << - take deep copy or not

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a string-class that among other overloads the inserter << and extractor >>. But something goes wrong here despite I use a copy-constructor where I take a deep copy of the objects member-variable. I suspect I need to do the same in the function that overloads the inserter >> (cin) but I cannot figure out how.

What happends is that when the user is entering his name in the conselewindow the cout returns nothing. Here is the scenario in the console

```
Enter a name:
```

the user enter for instance Sally
And the console outputs

```
your name is:
```

that is nothing.

So my question:

- Why is the string-array not left after calling the overloaded function?
- should I take a deep copy here? And if - how do I implement it.
- Any other reasons to this problem?

Extremely greatful for help!!!

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String {
   int str_len;

public:
   char *string;
   // default constructor
String() {
    str_len = 100;
    string = new char[str_len]();
    cout << "initialiserat default-constructor!\n";
}
// destrcutor
~String() {
    delete [] string;
    string = 0;
}


// copy constructor
String (const String &string_obj) {

    str_len = string_obj.str_len;

    if (string_obj.string) {
        string = new char[str_len];
        strncpy(string, string_obj.string, str_len);
    } else {
        string = 0;
    }
}

// Overloading assignment-operator
String operator=(const String& string_obj) {

    if (this == &string_obj) {
        return *this;
    }
    delete [] string;

    str_len = string_obj.str_len;

    if(string_obj.string) {
        string = new char[str_len];
        strncpy(string, string_obj.string, str_len);
    } else {
        string = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}

};

// overloading inserter <<
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, String obj) {

    stream << obj.string;
    return stream;
}

// overloading extractor >>
istream &operator>>(istream &stream, String obj) {

   cout << "Enter a name: ";
   stream >> obj.string;

   return stream;
}


int main() {

   String string3;

   cin >> string3;

   cout << "your name is: " << string3 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor have a serious problem: It doesn't terminate the string. Same with the copy-assignment operator.

Comment: You also have no checking for writing beyond the bounds of the allocated memory in the input operator.

Comment: And lastly: Don't have output in the input operator, let the caller write the prompt.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - thanks for your input. I will learn from this :-)

Comment: Please use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operator

```
istream &operator>>(istream &stream, String obj) {

   cout << "Enter a name: ";
   stream >> obj.string;

   return stream;
}
```

is invalid. Parameter `String obj` is a local variable of the function that will be destroyed after exiting the function. Define the operator as

```
istream &operator>>(istream &stream, String &obj) {

   cout << "Enter a name: ";
   stream >> obj.string;

   return stream;
}
```

Also define the output operator as

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const String &obj) {

    stream << obj.string;
    return stream;
}
```

Take into account that it is not a good design of the class when data member `string` is defined as public. Any body can change it.

```
class String {
   int str_len;

public:
   char *string;
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! this solved my problem. Concerning public and private, yes - I will make *string private and create an accessor member-function instead in due course of time. :-)